# How to compile frontend assets in Adonis app while it's running in a Docker container?

Tags: docker-compose, adonis.js

[This](https://github.com/msrumon/adonisjs-assets-compilation-issue) Adonis application fails compiling frontend assets while running inside Docker container. The app was scaffolded using `yarn` utility container defined at `docker-compose.yaml` file running `docker compose run --rm yarn create adonis-ts-app app` command and selecting `true` for ESLint, Prettier and Encore choices.

% **What Actually Happens** %

The application fails to compile assets. No sign of error from the running container:

```sh
$ docker compose logs app
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | yarn run v1.22.17
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | $ node ace serve --watch
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ info ]  building project...
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ info ]  starting http server...
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ encore ] Running webpack-dev-server ...
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ info ]  watching file system for changes
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [1645110239969] INFO (app/39 on b105e817d618): started server on 0.0.0.0:3333
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | │                                                        │
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | │    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3333               │
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | │    Watching filesystem for changes: YES                │
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | │    Encore server address: http://localhost:8080        │
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | │                                                        │
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ encore ]  DONE  Compiled successfully in 14380ms3:04:08 PM
docker-bind-mount-issue-app-1  | [ encore ] webpack compiled successfully
```

[Here](http://prnt.sc/26xtky1)'s the screenshot.

% **What I Expect** %

Assets should be compiled by *Webpack Encore* and I should get a confirmation like the following:

```sh
yarn run v1.22.15
$ node ace serve --watch
[ info ]  building project...
[ info ]  starting http server...
[ encore ] Running webpack-dev-server ...
[ info ]  watching file system for changes
[1645110644372] INFO (app/9208 on msrumon): started server on 0.0.0.0:3333
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                        │
│    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3333               │
│    Watching filesystem for changes: YES                │
│    Encore server address: http://localhost:8080        │
│                                                        │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
UPDATE: public\assets\manifest.json
UPDATE: public\assets\entrypoints.json
[ encore ]  DONE  Compiled successfully in 1449ms9:10:46 PM
[ encore ] webpack compiled successfully
```

[Here](http://prnt.sc/26xton4)'s the screenshot.

% **Reproduction Steps** %

1. Clone the above repository.
2. Install dependencies by running `docker compose run --rm yarn install`.
3. Start the development server by running `docker compose up --detach app`.
4. Browse http://localhost:3333 from any browser.

% **Extra Note** %

When I install the dependencies using `yarn` utility container (`docker compose run --rm yarn install`) and then start the server directly from host machine (`yarn run dev`), I get `'encore' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error:

```sh
$ docker compose run --rm yarn install
[+] Running 1/0
 - Network docker-bind-mount-issue_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

Done in 159.92s.

$ yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.15
$ node ace serve --watch
[ info ]  building project...
[ info ]  starting http server...
[ encore ] 'encore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[ warn ]  Underlying encore dev server died with "1 code"
[1645111433640] INFO (app/27364 on msrumon): started server on 0.0.0.0:3333
[ info ]  watching file system for changes
╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                        │
│    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:3333               │
│    Watching filesystem for changes: YES                │
│    Encore server address: http://localhost:8080        │
│                                                        │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Apparently `node_modules/.bin` was empty, but it wasn't when I ran `yarn install` directly on host machine. So, out of curiosity, I attempted to replicate the exact same issue for an Express app and `nodemon` binary to see whether the aforementioned directory stays empty or not. And I found that it wasn't empty. So I couldn't figure out where the problem was. I'd appreciate if anybody would be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple combinations of different solutions, and so far [this](https://github.com/msrumon/adonisjs-assets-compilation-issue/commit/16cfc7187c7131a59924fddcbbb5df733ebb576f) seems to be the most consistent "workaround" I've got. I'm still open for solution.